# Moving elements from one list to the other list

Tags: c#

```
List<String> s1;
List<String> s2;
```

I want to move n item from s1 to s2

```
say s1={"a","b","c"}
s2={"d","e","f"}
```

moving 2 elements from s1 to s2 would make

```
s1={"c"}
s2={"d","e","f","a","b"}
```

What is the good ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var s1 = new List<string>() { "a", "b", "c" };
var s2 = new List<string>() { "d", "e", "f" };
s2.AddRange(s1.Take(2)); 
s1.RemoveRange(0, 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the index of the item to move (in this case 0):

```
string item = s1[0];
s1.Remove(item);
s2.Add(item);
```

Comment: Note that this wouldn't work properly if the first list contains duplicate values.